# Require that a generic parameter contains a property with a specific string as a name C#?

Tags: c#, generics

So lets say I have two classes:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class Account2
{
    public string Name2{get;set;}
}
```

I want to write a generic method that will take in either one of these accounts and perform the exact same operation on both Name and Name2. So something like this.

```
public static void ProcessAccountNames<T>(List<T> accounts, string varName) where T: class 
{
    var name = account.GetType().GetProperty(varName).GetValue(account);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then I could call

```
ProcessAccountNames<Account>(myAccountList, "Name");
ProcessAccountNames<Account2>(myAccount2List, "Name2");
```

I was wondering if there was any way In the method signature for me to specify that type T must contain an attribute named varName. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use expressions:

```
public static void ProcessAccountNames<T>(List<T> accounts, Expression<Func<T, string>> propSelector) where T: class 
{
    string propName = ((MemberExpression)propSelector.Body).Member.Name;
    var name = account.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(account);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then use like this:

```
ProcessAccountNames<Account>(myAccountList, x => x.Name);
ProcessAccountNames<Account2>(myAccount2List, x => x.Name2);
```

Or using type inference:

```
ProcessAccountNames(myAccountList, x => x.Name);
ProcessAccountNames(myAccount2List, x => x.Name2);
```

Although this could potentially be abused e.g. `x => "some string"` resulting in an exception.

Another way would be to use `nameof`, which would add some compiler safety:

```
ProcessAccountNames(myAccountList, nameof(Account.Name));
```

The only 100% type-safe way would be to add an interface and implement forwarding properties as per Chad's answer.

---

An alternative would to be to use delegates:

```
public static void ProcessAccountNames<T>(List<T> accounts, Func<T, string> getName) where T: class
{
    var name = getName(account);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Which would still work like this:

```
ProcessAccountNames(myAccountList, x => x.Name);
ProcessAccountNames(myAccount2List, x => x.Name2);
```

Or you could provide a completely different function for retrieving a name, not restricted to property access:

```
ProcessAccountNames(myAccountList, x => "Some Name");
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. The answers were really helpful. I think this matches my requirement the best though.

Comment: I would say `Func<T, string>` instead of expression (`Expression<Func<T, object>>`) would be better based on what OP has described in question. @fooiey

Comment: @GuruStron Yes you're right about using `string` rather than `object`. I've updated the answer with an alternative implementation using delegates rather than expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Like Johnathan said, use an interface:

```
public interface INameable
{
     string Name { get; }
}
```

Then for the second class where Name2 is the name of the property, add a Name property that returns Name2 as its get value.

Then on the generic signature, add

```
where T : class, INameable
```

EDIT

Johnathan's answer is probably what you want, though it doesn't strictly behave the way you asked for.

Comment: as a side note: to shim over the name: for `Account2`: explicit interface implementation: `string INameable.Name => Name2;`